# Install certificate in Biztalk host

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm trying to find any reference for installing a decryption certificate to BizTalk host using PowerShell. I was unable to find any reference.

Comment: Imporing certificates is not BizTalk specific.      https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848630.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Installing certificates doesn't relate to BizTalk. 
You should install them in your machine server and afterwards choose it in BizTalk port.

As much as I know from my personal experience, you should install certificates using `certmgr.msc`.

If you need to use powershell to install - search for an installation script in the web.

After the installation you can choose it on BizTalk port under `Security` tab.